# SDL2 Event Loop on Android - cannot push any new events into the queue

Tags: android, android-ndk, sdl

I am trying to use SDL2 in my new Android application, it should work well:

http://wilbefast.com/2011/11/11/recent-sdl-android-goodies/

It compiles without a single problem and there is a sample project so it is quite easy to start using it. I compiled the library and started with my application, created an event loop - as in SDL 1.2 and tried to push some events into it by function:

```
int SDL_PushEvent(SDL_Event * event);
```

However, it always fails with error value -1. I just defined SDL_main function for this source file:

http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/6bb657898f55/src/main/android/SDL_android_main.cpp

My SDL_main function contains simple event loop:

```
SDL_Event event;

for (;;)
{
    SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type)
    {
case SDL_QUIT:
    return;
    case SOME_EVENT:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and that's all, no threads, no mutexes, no waits, just a simple main function. I noticed that my event loop process some events, their event.type equals to 2151293988, It looks their source is SDLSurface instance, which is created in the Java code: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/6bb657898f55/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java

Why `SDL_PushEvent` function doesn't work? Has anybody an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: It seems I found the reason. The queue was just not started! I though the queue runs the SDL2 automatically when initializing... I have added `SDL_StartEventLoop();` call into the main function and it works now - almost five hours of my live are gone with such a little omission...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDL queue does not start automatically after init, it must be started explicitly by calling `SDL_StartEventLoop();`